# JQuery code does not run

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am very new to jquery, please help me in running the app on  [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/blackdynamo/yxhzU/). I have added below resource files in my app, but still it is not rendering the color blocks.

These is what I have included in my head tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="jquery.mobile.carousel.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"/>
<script src="jquery.ui.ipad.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  >
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#carousel1").carousel();
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: you dont' need http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js And use the firebug console. You might have an error.

Comment: its working fine as you send the link. so what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="jquery.mobile.carousel.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"/>
<script src="jquery.ui.ipad.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  >
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#carousel1").carousel();
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

My suggestions would be:

- [Upgrade jQM to the latest version](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) as you are using a RC
- Close your tags properly as suggested by @MarkRhodes
- update the links to your frameworks as suggested by @feco
- [Use `pageInit()`, not `$(document).ready()`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html)

Might look something like:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- I'm asuming this is where you are getting these from -->
<!-- https://github.com/blackdynamo/jQuery-Mobile-Carousel -->
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.carousel.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.ipad.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  >
    $('#pageId').live('pageinit',function(event){
        $("#carousel1").carousel();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are also using self-closing script tags which aren't always allowed. i.e. switch

```
<script src="..." type="text/javascript"/>
```

for:

```
<script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>
```

see: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the jquery UI framework,
Add jquery UI to your head tag

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function(){
        $("#carousel1").carousel();
});
```